# Testing with supertest and mocha fails to resolve promise

Tags: redis, promise, mocha.js, bluebird, supertest

I'm testing my rest application (made with hapi on node) with mocha (3.2) and supertest (3.0) using promises.

It stops after timeout and returns error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

I already tried to increment timeout but it didn't work.

If I add a `done()` call I get:

> Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.

Could you help me please?

This is my test:

```js
...
const request = require('supertest');
const redis = require('redis');
const bluebird = require("bluebird");
bluebird.promisifyAll(redis.RedisClient.prototype);
const config = require('../src/config/tests');

describe('Routing', function () {

    let url = 'http://localhost:8080';

    let storage = redis.createClient({
        host: config.config.host,
        port: config.config.port
    });

    it('should pass', function (done) {
        let username = 'user',
            userHash = md5(username),
            data = {
                user_id: username,
                sess_id: 'session'
            };
        return storage.delAsync("users:" + userHash)
            .then(result => {
                return request(url)
                    .post('/login')
                    .send(data)
                    .expect(201)
                    .expect({info: true});
            })
            .then(response => {
                return storage.hgetallAsync("users:" + userHash);
            })
            .then(result => {
                assert({user_id: userHash}, result);
            })
    });

});
```

Comment: If you return a promise, you shouldn't have `done` in function signature (not calling it is not enough). Have you tried to debug a promise? If it's pending or long, this is the reason why it's not working.

Comment: I tried inserting `console.log`. Everything is as expected. The execution reaches the last `then` and logs `result`, but the test finishes with error on timeout.

Comment: Again, there is `function (done) {` in the code you've posted.

Comment: It was only in the signature but it was not used in the body of the function. Incredibly removing it solved the problem!!! Would you like to write an answer so I can check it?

Comment: Sure. Of course, this is how `done` works. It is signature that makes the spec async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying `done` parameter in function signature marks the test as asynchronous. And not calling it results in pending test.

If it is specified with `function (done) { ... }`, it should be called. This is what the error says. And it shouldn't be specified if the spec was made asynchronous by returning a promise.

Comment: That was even clear in the error message! Thank you very much for your help